# Why .o (object file) links faster than .lib ( static library)?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

At my workplace, our product compiles into an executable, with sub-projects linking as static-libraries(.lib) or shared-libraries(.dll). We use Microsoft C++ compiler.

Recently one of my co-workers converted a sub-project target from .lib ( static-library) to .o (object file), and linking time for that sub-project decreased drastically. Earlier, the .lib would take around 1.5 mins to link. With linking to .o, linking time is almost 5-6 seconds.

Why is linking .lib slower that .o ?

Comment: Interesting topic. My guess would be that it is because object files are already in a convenient format for the linker, in the structure expected by it.

Comment: Hmm, that is not a sensible thing to do, an .obj file can store the code for only a single source code file.  The linker is not that easily fooled and probably still recognizes it as a library.  What you probably did is screw up the debug info generation for the library, the .pdb file, that tends the be the expensive part of linking.  Ought to produce a pretty unpleasant surprise some day when you need to debug it.  Look into the /DEBUG:fastlink option, available since VS2015 Update 1.  And of course spinning off code into a separate module, a DLL, can significantly reduce build times.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is compiling source code to create an object file then you're performing no linking at all.  This means that any reference to external functions and variables present in your source code won't work as their addresses weren't resolved yet.

https://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html